# Unable to add dynamic block for versioning_configuration for aws s3 in terraform version 4.0.0

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

When trying to add dynamic block for aws s3 versioning configuration , I'm getting the error 'versioning_configuration' argument is required. please find below code instance and suggest the best answer.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "firehose_to_s3" {
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.firehose_to_s3.id
acl = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "firehose_to_s3" {
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.firehose_to_s3.id

dynamic "versioning_configuration" {
#value of replicate is false and true.
for_each = var.replicate ? ["yes"] : []
content {
status = "Enabled"
}

}
}
```

below is the error I'm getting
The argument "versioning_configuration" is required, but no definition was
found.

Comment: The version is 4.0.0

Comment: Could you explain better why you need to use the dynamic block and the for_each? You want to enable or disable bucket versioning based on a variable?

Comment: Versioning configuration is a `Required` parameter, it can't be optional: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_versioning#versioning_configuration.

Comment: @DaniloCacace yes, I need to enable or disable based on variable. And the value of replicate is true and false. Can't we add dynamic blocks for required arguments?

Comment: It will be simpler to use a count or a condition in the block, if you need only to enable or disable versioning

Comment: @DaniloCacace
Tried to create multiple S3 buckets with the below-provided code still facing an error.

`The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.`

Comment: Can you please provide the cone snippet? You setted the variable replicate? I proposed two solutions is not clear what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to enable or disable versioning based on a boolean variable you can do with count

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "firehose_to_s3" {
  count = var.replicate ? 1 : 0

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.firehose_to_s3.id

  "versioning_configuration" {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

This because by default the versioning is not enabled, so you could not create resource when you don't want it.

Or you can add a condition on `status` variable, like

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "firehose_to_s3" {

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.firehose_to_s3.id

  "versioning_configuration" {
    status =   var.replicate ? "Enabled" : "Suspended"
  }
}
```